# How to calculate fuse i2t rating when current is known?

Tags: simulation, fuses, math, formula-derivation

How do I convert the fuse current rating to the i2t value? For example, in [this circuit simulator](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/), when adding a fuse, the only values that can be specified are the i2t value and resistance.  The [fuse I am attempting to simulate](https://cdn.automationdirect.com/static/specs/efuses500.pdf) says 32mA.

Comment: You can't. You need to also know the fuse's trip time.

Comment: @Hearth I added a link to the fuse datasheet, where they actually list the i2t value (who knew?!) But if it was unknown, how would one calculate the i2t if trip time was known?

Comment: it's in the name: square the current and multiply by time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply get these parameters from the fuse data sheet or compute from the curves.

[Here I gave you some fuses to blow and sliders to increase](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgDOB0Y2CcDFOXEBGMkBMMsHY8BmMADiwDYE8QBWCGkAFkICgAndPc9ciLEkjwh9IjEiwDOIfoJIRCNLCDnh0IAGYBDADYSApiwDuTMdJrc0cJVnPgWAY04XeTs92HQY5LukhpyJHhgjHDMFHhwBIR6ALRojCBxYCwAbiaCNtyMpirCTBBodKoeNOwgcNwKSv7yiqoYycZVyhDZsvJG6FZurpl2HGho1S6D1rYFMJ1oPjXoQ0LSUz59oz3JAObpPW3SAsUsjMHSWAmmWCfo-MXQ5GiEIOSQRKoALmwArgaHCSetGYeXQQeMC3e6PZ4QN6fA5HRSCCq0K7TdxQEF3B5Pe4QLS6L6w7Llbg0AnI65osGY1Q4-QwhLkAFDQT0vikMmgjEQjQ6GnfB4XRl8n6s4Hs8FYrm42m0boCmjdHBA1GiynY7l4n57FQyBYi9FiqlqqXEhKWJTG6R4JS6imc6nq2gjbrmPiWtl6lUSmkAexAYISrXgqEwsDAXCwcEIoRohCGDGDsEi5HMNlUSnurB9EHpqkOCFRsDDEajMZT8ZgieTDDQ0lUGfQfpA1GYNDjkBLVcg3Gq%20ZghcjjGjsZYhEE4rLgZQk6DnmrAGFNAAHTT2ACWL00ADt7AYR8UawkAEp6CQriTrrcGIA) the surge load.

Now you enter 0.000047 for i2t and compute R from 3200mV/32mA = 100 then add your load and watch the fuse get hot. Time sample around 500us for real-time .